# Parsing JSON object and sub-elements

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I just need to know proper method to parse the JSON string. 
Here is my sample JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "my_response": [
            {
                "name": "XXX",
                "Area": "XXX",
                "Num": 123
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "other_response": [
            {
                "message": "Hello",
                "status": "Success",
                "flag_value": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to parse `flag_value` in a `String`

I tried this method

```
NSString *str1 = [json valueForKeyPath:@"other_response. flag_value"];
NSLog(@"str %@",str1);
```

And my output is some what like this

```
str (
  "<null>",
    (
      1
    )
)
```

But I want my output to be a string like this:

```
1
```

Comment: Is your JSON response a `NSString` or you already serialized it into a `NSArray/NSDictionary` object?

Comment: Your json doesn't have a `@"other_response. flag_value"` key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[{"my_response":[{"name":"XXX","Area":"XXX","Num":123}]},{"other_response":[{"message":"Hello","status":"Success","flag_value":"1"}]}]
```

actually your `Json response` Start in `Array` so follow this step

**Step-1**

```
NSArray *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:Kniloptions error:nil];
```

**Step-2**

in here you are get 2 Dictionaries

```
NSString *FlagStr;
for (NSMutableDictionary *temp in jsonDict)
 {

   NSArray *secondOption=[temp objectForKey:@"other_response"];
    
      for (NSMutableDictionary *second in secondOption)
       {
          FlagStr=[second objectForKey:@"flag_value"];
         }
    
        }
```

**Choice no-2**

I am not try this but May be it work for you , once check

**Step-1**

```
NSArray *jsonDict = [[[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:Kniloptions error:nil]objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"other_response"];
```

**Step-2**

```
 NSString *FlagStr;

   for (NSMutableDictionary *second in secondOption)
       {
          FlagStr=[temp objectForKey:@"flag_value"];
         }
```

**Choice no-3**

you can directly fetch the string value I am not try this but May be it work for you , once check

```
 NSString *flage = [[[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:Kniloptions error:nil]objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"other_response"]objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"flag_value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your JSON would be better formatted like the following:

```
{
  "my_response": {
    "name": "XXX",
    "area": "XXX",
    "num": "XXX"
  },
  "other_response": {
    "message": "Hello",
    "status": "success",
    "flag_value": "1"
  }
}
```

Then you can use the following code to access your data:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"my_response\": {\"name\": \"XXX\",\"area\": \"XXX\",\"num\": \"XXX\"},\"other_response\": {\"message\": \"Hello\",\"status\": \"success\",\"flag_value\": \"1\"}}";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
NSLog(@"str: %@", [jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"other_response.flag_value"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Format your Json array like this way.

{
  "my_response": {"name": "XXX","area": "XXX","num": "XXX"
  },
  "other_response": {"message": "Hello","status": "success","flag_value": "1"
  }
}

**Step : 2**
```

Use AFNetworking for HTTP Client

```
- (void)yourMethod{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", your_service_url];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

   AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
   [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

   NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                           your_parameters_list,
                            nil];
        NSMutableURLRequest *jsonRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                path:urlString
                                                          parameters:params];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:jsonRequest success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@" Success %@", JSON);

        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary1 = [JSON valueForKey:@"my_response"];
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary2 = [JSON valueForKey:@"other_response"];

                NSString* name = [jsonDictionary1 valueForKey:@“name”];
                NSString* area = [jsonDictionary1 valueForKey:@"name"];
                NSString* num =  [jsonDictionary1 valueForKey:@"num"];




    } failure: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Fail %@", [error userInfo]);

        NSLog(@“Error %@", [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);


    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As accepted above brother Anbu.Karthick answer.But I want to give answer for this

```
   NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourResponseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

   for (int i =0; i<[jsonArray count]; i++)

   {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];

    NSString *strFlag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[dict objectForKey:@"other_response"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"flag_value"]];

    NSLog(@"The strFlag is-%@",strFlag);

   }
```

Comment: instead of NSString *strFlag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[dict objectForKey:@"other_response"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"flag_value"]];

Comment: Try this logic NSString *strFlag = [[[dict objectForKey:@"other_response"]  valueForKey:@"flag_value"]objectAtIndex:i];

Comment: actually what u need exactly the above answer is accepted and its worked